# Matplotlib animate fill_between shape

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to animate a `fill_between` shape inside matplotlib and I don't know how to update the data of the `PolyCollection`. Take this simple example: I have two lines and I am always filling between them. Of course, the lines change and are animated.

Here is a dummy example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Init plot:
f_dummy = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(6, 6));
axes_dummy = f_dummy.add_subplot(111);

# Plotting:
line1, = axes_dummy.plot(X, line1_data, color = 'k', linestyle = '--', linewidth=2.0, animated=True);
line2, = axes_dummy.plot(X, line2_data, color = 'Grey', linestyle = '--', linewidth=2.0, animated=True);
fill_lines = axes_dummy.fill_between(X, line1_data, line2_data, color = '0.2', alpha = 0.5, animated=True);

f_dummy.show();
f_dummy.canvas.draw();
dummy_background = f_dummy.canvas.copy_from_bbox(axes_dummy.bbox);

# [...]    

# Update plot data:
def update_data():
   line1_data = # Do something with data
   line2_data = # Do something with data
   f_dummy.canvas.restore_region( dummy_background );
   line1.set_ydata(line1_data);
   line2.set_ydata(line2_data);
   
   # Update fill data too

   axes_dummy.draw_artist(line1);
   axes_dummy.draw_artist(line2);

   # Draw fill too
   
   f_dummy.canvas.blit( axes_dummy.bbox );
```

The question is how to update the `fill_between` `Poly` data based on `line1_data` and `line2_data` each time `update_data()` is called and draw them before `blit` ("# Update fill data too" & "# Draw fill too"). I tried `fill_lines.set_verts()` without success and could not find an example.

Comment: You may need to delete and fully re-draw every frame.  The `*collection` objects do not play nice with updating.  The reason is that they have thrown away all of the meta-data that would allow you to map between data-space and draw-space, and just keep a list of what to draw.  This is a trade off to render them quickly.

Comment: Do you mean to use f_dummy.canvas.draw() inside update_data? I started with this but unfortunately I need a fast plotting since I am processing and playing a signal in real-time and I need the plotting not to affect the playback (calling draw() stalls the playback). If you know a fast threading trick to redraw everything while playing the sounds, would be nice - I called draw with threading.start(...). I know there are other faster plotting libraries but I prefer sticking to matplotlib and the restore/blit trick worked fast enough for me.

Answer (score 15):

Ok, as someone pointed out, we are dealing with a collection here, so we will have to delete and redraw. So somewhere in the `update_data` function, delete all collections associated with it:

```py
axes_dummy.collections.clear()
```

and draw the new "fill_between" PolyCollection:

```
axes_dummy.fill_between(x, y-sigma, y+sigma, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
```

A similar trick is required to overlay an unfilled contour plot on top of a filled one, since an unfilled contour plot is a Collection as well (of lines I suppose?).

Comment: If you want to remove just one collection, you can use `coll.get_label()` to get the right one provided that you have labelled the collection first.

Answer (score 5):

this is not my answer, but I found it most useful:

http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/animation-of-a-fill-between-region-td42814.html

Hi Mauricio,
Patch objects are a bit more difficult to work with than line objects, because unlike line objects are a step removed from the input data supplied by the user.  There is an example similar to what you want to do here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/histogram.html

Basically, you need to modify the vertices of the path at each frame.  It might look something like this:

```
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0,10000])

x = np.linspace(6000.,7000., 5)
y = np.ones_like(x)

collection = plt.fill_between(x, y)

def animate(i):
    path = collection.get_paths()[0]
    path.vertices[:, 1] *= 0.9

animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                        frames=25, interval=30)
```

Take a look at path.vertices to see how they're laid out.
Hope that helps,
   Jake

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use anitmation, or to remove everything from your figure to update only filling, you could use this way :

call `fill_lines.remove()` and then call again `axes_dummy.fill_between()` to draw new ones. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to what most answers here stated, it is not necessary to remove and redraw a `PolyCollection` returned by `fill_between` each time you want to update its data. Instead, you can modify the `vertices` and `codes` attribute of the underlying `Path` object. Let's assume you've created a `PolyCollection` via

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#dummy data
x = np.arange(10)
y0 = x-1
y1 = x+1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
p = ax.fill_between(x,y0,y1)
```

and now you want to update `p` with new data `xnew`, `y0new` and `y1new`. Then what you could do is

```py
v_x = np.hstack([xnew[0],xnew,xnew[-1],xnew[::-1],xnew[0]])
v_y = np.hstack([y1new[0],y0new,y0new[-1],y1new[::-1],y1new[0]])
vertices = np.vstack([v_x,v_y]).T
codes = np.array([1]+(2*len(xnew)+1)*[2]+[79]).astype('uint8')

path = p.get_paths()[0]
path.vertices = vertices
path.codes = codes
```

Explanation: `path.vertices` contains the vertices of the patch drawn by `fill_between` including additional start and end positions, `path.codes` contains instructions on how to use them (1=MOVE POINTER TO, 2=DRAW LINE TO, 79=CLOSE POLY).

Answer (score 0):

initialize pyplot interactive mode

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
```

use the optional label argument when plotting the fill:

```
plt.fill_between(
    x, 
    y1, 
    y2, 
    color="yellow", 
    label="cone"
)

plt.pause(0.001) # refresh the animation
```

later in our script we can select by label to delete that specific fill or a list of fills, thus animating on a object by object basis.

```
axis = plt.gca()

fills = ["cone", "sideways", "market"]   

for collection in axis.collections:
    if str(collection.get_label()) in fills:
        collection.remove()
        del collection

plt.pause(0.001)
```

you can use the same label for groups of objects you would like to delete; or otherwise encode the labels with tags as needed to suit needs

for example if we had fills labelled:

"cone1" "cone2" "sideways1"

```
if "cone" in str(collection.get_label()):
```

would sort to delete both those prefixed with "cone".

You can also animate lines in the same manner

```
for line in axis.lines:
```

Answer (score 0):

another idiom which will work is too keep a *list* of your plotted objects; this method seems to work with any type of plotted object.

```
# plot interactive mode on
plt.ion()

# create a dict to store "fills" 
# perhaps some other subclass of plots 
# "yellow lines" etc. 
plots = {"fills":[]}

# begin the animation
while 1: 

    # cycle through previously plotted objects
    # attempt to kill them; else remember they exist
    fills = []
    for fill in plots["fills"]:
        try:
            # remove and destroy reference
            fill.remove()
            del fill
        except:
            # and if not try again next time
            fills.append(fill)
            pass
    plots["fills"] = fills   

    # transformation of data for next frame   
    x, y1, y2 = your_function(x, y1, y2)

    # fill between plot is appended to stored fills list
    plots["fills"].append(
        plt.fill_between(
            x,
            y1,
            y2,
            color="red",
        )
    )

    # frame rate
    plt.pause(1)
```