# How to correct error from python fill betweeen, TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not iterable

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime-error

The code snippet below prints out the type and shape for the x, y1, and y2 inputs to the fill_between command.  I'm getting the following runtime error "TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not iterable".   How do I correct this?

```
        x_fill = x_fill.reshape((n_steps_fcst, ))
        y1_fill = y1_fill.reshape((n_steps_fcst, ))
        y2_fill = y2_fill.reshape((n_steps_fcst, ))

        print('type(x_fill): ', type(x_fill), ', x_fill.shape: ', x_fill.shape)
        print('type(y1_fill): ', type(y1_fill), ', y1_fill.shape: ', y1_fill.shape)
        print('type(y2_fill): ', type(y2_fill), ', y2_fill.shape: ', y2_fill.shape)

        ax_y.append(fig.add_subplot(ny, n_columns, iy * n_columns + 1))

        lin, = ax_y[iy].fill_between(x_fill, y1_fill, y2_fill)
```

The output is

```
type(x_fill):  <class 'numpy.ndarray'> , x_fill.shape:  (99,)
type(y1_fill):  <class 'numpy.ndarray'> , y1_fill.shape:  (99,)
type(y2_fill):  <class 'numpy.ndarray'> , y2_fill.shape:  (99,)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Documents/git_spork/Project/time_series_plot_2.py", line 371, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Documents/git_spork/Project/time_series_plot_2.py", line 276, in main
    lin, = ax_y[iy].fill_between(x_fill, y1_fill, y2_fill)

TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Use `lin = ax.fill_...`, instead of `lin, = ax.fill_...`, i.e. no comma!

Comment: Ok, that appears to have worked.  But I have it in a loop, how to set x, y1, y2, using lin.  I used lin.set_xdata before, but that does that exist for fill_between?

Comment: It looks like you want to [animate fill_between shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120801/matplotlib-animate-fill-between-shape).